# Map pages in a different process's address space

Tags: linux, memory, process

Memory in another process's address space can be read and modified using `ptrace(2)` or `process_vm_readv(2)`/`process_vm_writev(2)`, however I can't find a syscall to allocate new memory in another process's address space.

The only way I can currently think of is to write instructions to the process's code to make it call `mmap` itself, then stop it after the call and revert the code modification. However, this is error prone and seems like a very hacky solution.

Is there a syscall I've missed that allows mapping new pages in another process's address space? If not, is there a cleaner way to execute code in the target process's address space?

Comment: Q: Why would you want one process to alter another process's address space?

Comment: You trying to port an application from Microsoft Windows - where it is possible to map new pages into another process's address space, i.e. VirtualAllocEx, WriteProcessMemory, etc.?

Comment: @paulsm4 To allocate new pages to copy data into (using `process_vm_writev`), if the existing mappings are not large enough

Comment: @fpmurphy, no, I'm writing a new program native to Linux that requires this functionality

Comment: @vktec.  There is no syscall that will map new pages in another processes address space.

Comment: @fpmurphy In that case, do you know of a better approach to injecting a mmap call than just replacing (and subsequently restoring) the current instruction with ptrace?

Comment: Sadly, it seems the kernel developers are not keen to such a feature: https://lkml.org/lkml/2019/5/15/1315

Comment: What is your exact use case? Could you give slightly more details? Would it be feasible for you to use a debugger to make "mmap" call inside the target process?